# Click "play" button on website from command line (PHP)

Tags: php, command-line, webautomation

I'm using Ampache (a web based music player) on my machine, and I'm trying to automate the
"play_democratic" function listed in the below code in bold.

This Function simply plays the music (looks like a play button on the webpage)
but I want the function to be executed via the command line (xubuntu 13.10)

So it would look something like this

```
`sudo php show_democratic.inc.php play_democratic`
```

Note, the website uses authentication so I'm not sure how to pass that information into the command line or if I need to create a shell script to execute the function.

I'm running xubuntu 13.10

See full PHP file contents below.

```
<?php
/* vim:set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab: */
/**
*
* LICENSE: GNU General Public License, version 2 (GPLv2)
* Copyright 2001 - 2013 Ampache.org
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2
* as published by the Free Software Foundation.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
* Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
*
*/

$string = $democratic->is_enabled() ? sprintf(T_('%s Playlist') ,$democratic->name) :   T_('Democratic Playlist');
UI::show_box_top($string , 'info-box');
?>
<div id="information_actions">
<ul>
<?php if ($democratic->is_enabled()) { ?>
<li>
<?php echo T_('Cooldown'); ?>:<?php echo $democratic->f_cooldown; ?>
</li>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (Access::check('interface','75')) { ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo AmpConfig::get('web_path');
?>/democratic.php?action=manage"><?php  echo UI::get_icon('server_lightning', 
T_('Configure Democratic Playlist')); ?></a>
<?php echo T_('Configure Democratic Playlist'); ?>
</li>
<?php if ($democratic->is_enabled()) { ?>
<li>
<?php echo Ajax::button('?page=democratic&action=send_playlist&democratic_id=' .
scrub_out($democratic->id),'all', T_(**'Play'),'play_democratic'); ?>**
<?php echo T_('Play Democratic Playlist'); ?>
</li>
<li>
<?php echo Ajax::button('?page=democratic&action=clear_playlist&democratic_id=' . 
scrub_out($democratic->id),'delete', T_('Clear Playlist'),'clear_democratic'); ?>
<?php echo T_('Clear Playlist'); ?>
</li>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</ul>

</div>
<?php UI::show_box_bottom(); ?>
```

Comment: Ok this is my first post on this site, so sorry about my sucky formatting with the code layout.

Comment: where you see **'Play'),'play_democratic'); ?>** was ment to be bold.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to interact with a web application from command line, you do not need to modify the web app code. you can simply call the URL via a command line utility like cUrl.